# Asterisk PHPAGI Issue

Tags: php, asterisk

I'm using PHPAGI which I've used countless times before.
However, it doesnt appear to be behaving on my new test server.

When I try wait_for_digit, it immediately returns and the Asterisk CLI shows

```
WARNING[11873][C-00000000]: channel.c:3660 ast_waitfordigit_full: The FD we were waiting for has something waiting. Waitfordigit returning numeric 1
```

Here is my php code:

```
#!/usr/bin/php
<?php
require 'phpagi.php';

$agi = new AGI();

$test = $agi->wait_for_digit(); //lets try to simply get asterisk to wait. 

?>
```

and my dialplan

```
exten => 123,1,Answer()
exten => 123,n,AGI(/var/lib/asterisk/agi-bin/voicemail.php,test,1)
```

Comment: If I do multiple `wait_for_digit`s, I get the same warning multiple times.

Comment: platform and asterisk version?

Comment: This script is working fine on Asterisk 13.7.1 and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.